# Git command(s) to restore fork to current source code (as it is in main repository) it was forked from

Tags: git, github, git-fork

About 3 months ago, I forked a repository on GitHub.  I submitted a pull request to the main repo where it was forked from.  I'd like to start fresh again since there has been so many updates to the original code.  What is the best course of action and what Git commands would I call to get my fork to the current source code?  I've also sent pull requests, so I'd like to undo (or disable) those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is git rebase https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase and git merge https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge for this problem.
With rebase the commits to the main branch will be applyed to your dev brach.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/conceptual-overview